# PhoneGap AngularJS Strongloop MongoDB Firebase

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, cordova, firebase

I'm trying to setup an alternative to Firebase with loopback API REST(with mongodb connector) in NodeJS, when I implement it with the $http ressource to my PhoneGap apps in AngularJS, 
it is not update in realtime like Firebase.

My factory is like:

```
 function syncUsers(){
return $http.get(userUrl).then(function(res){
        return res.data;
    });
```

in my controllers:

```
UserSrv.syncUsers().then(function(res)
{ $scope.data.users = res});
```

my question is : why my apps don't update the old data, and why I need to refresh the apps to have the new data ?

Thank you.

Comment: And you question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok even if I don't know how to implement it, I need to use pub/sub

Strong loop work on it.

https://github.com/strongloop/strong-pubsub/issues/7